# Port missing when running Docker image?

Tags: docker, go

I'm learning Docker and trying to run my image on my Windows 10 PC. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Build the Go API-
FROM golang:1.17
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app/server
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/server/main"]
```

I then ran the command `docker build -t my-go-app .` and successfully built the image. Then I tried `docker run -p 8080:8081 my-go-app` and in the shell I got the output `Initializing server...Server ready at Port`. My Go code is supposed to print out the port number at the end but its missing? I specified it in the `docker run` command to be 8080 so why is it not mapping correctly? Below is the relevant portion of my Go code in case it helps. When running locally, I have it pulling the Port from an environment variable. Do I have to do something similar in Docker?

```
type App struct {
    Port           string
}

func (app *App) Init(config *config.Config) {
    fmt.Print("Initializing server...")
    app.Port = config.Port
    fmt.Println("Server ready at Port", app.Port)
}
```

Comment: You still have to configure your application. You can use environment variables in the container as well. The `-p` flag is for the Docker runtime, your program does not have access to that

Comment: Thanks! So I updated my run command to `docker run -p 8080:8081 --env PORT=8080 my-go-app` and now it displays `Initializing server...Server ready at Port 8080` as expected. But when I go to *http://localhost:8080/* in the browser I get a "*This page isn't working*" error. When running locally, it displays "*Hello world*". Is there another piece missing for this too?

Comment: Aha! I switched it to `docker run -p **8081:8080** --env PORT=8080 my-go-app` and it works when I go to *localhost/8081*!

Answer (score 0):

GO defaults to port 8080 and with your configuration after adding `--env PORT=8080` it has the requested port also.

on top of that, when using the `-p` option the first port is the port to expose on the host OS and the second is for the one the application is exposing in the container, example format `-p HOST_PORT:GO_EXPOSED_PORT`, [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) on the option

Comment: @Notorious776 please accept the answer if it solves your issue